# how to set text in mouseover array leaflet

Tags: leaflet, mouseover

I have problem to display text when mouseover certain point.
This is my code:

```
      for(var e=0;e<xmlStation.getElementsByTagName("station").length;e++) {    

        var lat=xmlStation.getElementsByTagName("station")[e].getAttribute("lat");
        var lon=xmlStation.getElementsByTagName("station")[e].getAttribute("lon");

        // Posiziona l'icona dell'evento nel punto di coordinate

        // Legge le varie proprietà dell'evento
        var stat=xmlStation.getElementsByTagName("station")[e].getAttribute("code");
        var Network=xmlStation.getElementsByTagName("station")[e].getAttribute("netid");
        var center=xmlStation.getElementsByTagName("station")[e].getAttribute("source");
        var loc=xmlStation.getElementsByTagName("station")[e].getAttribute("name");
        var image = L.icon({
          iconUrl: imagename,
          iconSize: [magvis, magvis],
          iconAnchor: [(magvis)/2, (magvis)/2]
        });
        var markerPos = new L.LatLng(lat,lon);
        var LMarker = new L.marker(markerPos,{icon:image}).bindPopup(info,{maxWidth: "auto"}).on('mouseover', function (e) {
          Popup = L.popup()
          .setLatLng(markerPos)
          .setContent('Centro di acquisizione = '+center+'<br>'+'Network = '+Network+'<br>'+'Codice Stazione = '+stat+'<br>'+'Località = '+loc)
          .openOn(mymap);
        }).addTo(mymap)
        ArrayStation.push(LMarker);
      }
      for(var e=0;e<xmlStation.getElementsByTagName("station").length;e++) {    
        mymap.removeLayer(ArrayM[e]);    
      }
 
      makeshake=true;

    });
```

When I try to execute, it set the image in right position, but on event on mouseover it repeat  only the last element.
Why do it happen?

Comment: Missing closures on `markerPos`, `center`, `Network`, `stat` and `loc`.

Comment: Please, can you suggested an example? How I have to do?

Comment: Read https://stackoverflow.com/questions/111102/how-do-javascript-closures-work

Comment: I have not understand. You mean that I have to do for set every variable a function?

Comment: The incorrect visualization is the mouseover function. The bindPopup show right info and when I use bindPopu to set image, it is put in the right position

Comment: There is anybody that can help me?

Comment: Solved.
I have change my script as a function inide the cicle for.
In that way when exit from function the closure is applied and every mark is shows well